# Extract HTML tags and its content from a string

Tags: performance, php, comparative-review, regex, dom

## Goal

I want to extract HTML tags and its content from a string. The content (input) is queried from WordPress database.

#### Sample data (input)

I extract this dummy data from my WordPress database: https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/tan
I believe this should cover all the needed tags to parse.

#### Expectation (output)

Accepting a HTML-format string as input.
The output should be able to return a string which could be any of these:

1. The HTML element string itself
2. Attributes string of the HTML element
3. Text nodes, child nodes string of the HTML element

#### My concern

- Which solutions take less execution time?
- Which solutions save more server memory?
- Security vulnerable of each solutions.

## Solutions

I've come up with a 2 solutions by myself. It works fine, but I don't know which one is good for my case.

#### [Regex pattern](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
$el = 'li'; // Ex
$match = []; // Reserving for results

/**
 * Regex - extract HTML tag and its content
 * Array map:
 * x[0] = everything
 * x[1] = open tag
 * x[2] = attributes
 * x[3] = content & end tag
 * x[4] = content only
 * 
 * Note for content: including text node + children node
 */
$reg = '/(<'.$el.'(.*?)>)((\n*?.*?\n*?)<\/'.$el.'>|)/';

if (preg_match($reg, $html_str, $match)) { echo 'Moving onward!';}
```

**Result**: [see demo of regex](https://3v4l.org/BQtNX)

#### [DOM object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$content = mb_convert_encoding(
    get_the_content(null, true), # WordPress func, it gives input str
    'HTML-ENTITIES',
    'UTF-8'
);
$dom->loadHTML($content);

$el = $doc->getElementsByTagName('li');
```

**Result**: returning a DOMNodeList and I have to do few more tasks to print it to a string which can be used.

Comment: They do different things, with different behavior in various cases of malformed or nested tags. It would be better to show us your real code, in context, with a clear statement of the task that your code accomplishes, so that we can advise you properly. See [ask].

Comment: Those are my real code, unless you want to see my repo. The context accepts WordPress content as input. A sample data were added as demo of regex. https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/tan

Comment: As always, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3690024) for important information on parsing HTML with regex.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using regex to parse valid html will work (and you might call it *beautiful*) until it doesn't work... then you'll bend over backwards (over and over) each time you encounter an anomaly then try to write a patch for the pattern.

Allow me to notify you of a simple, [valid html occurrence](https://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/) that will break your sample pattern:

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/qjFpO)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/html_5/tags/html_link_tag_example.css">
```

It would match because your `li` needle is not immediately followed by a word boundary character (`\b`). Is this a simple thing to fix? Yes, but my point remains -- regex is an inappropriate tool for parsing valid html.

I generally rely on DomDocument for most cases and when XPath makes life simpler, I use that to perform clean, readable queries on the document.

This is one time when focussing on speed is a moot point -- speed is the least of your worries.  What good is speed if the results are bogus? The goal should be to design a robust and reliable script using DOM-aware techniques.

Comment: Didn't see that comin'. But if I just use it in a very small scope of HTML then maybe it's ok right? Only makup tags, not meta tags.

Comment: Btw, I take advise about the speed. But what about memory consuming? (didn't got coffee last night untill this morning. Sorry)

Comment: Okay, one last example breakage: https://3v4l.org/0J5Wt.  Now, to answer your comment about "_Can I do it? What if I do it just a little bit? And only when it feels right? And I'll promise to stop as soon as I can._"  That right there, my friend, is how people wind up pregnant and battling horrid STDs.  My advice: **abstain**.  Draw a good thick line in the sand and bellow the mantra: "Thou shall not parse valid html with regex."  Can I stop you? No.  I can only give advice about what I think is best.  Is there a greater cost in speed and memory? Certainly.  Is it worth it?  Certainly.

Comment: You are absolute right. I've just encountered a problem that it's ridiculous hard to solve by regex. It's querying a child node of an element. Because regex is just a fixed pattern, I couldn't get as much as I want in easy way. Now I really few sorry for changing to regex solution, it took another day good for nothing. Also like you say, yeah, regex is not a good choice when it comes to HTML. Thanks, I've been enlightened. Your example is so wonderful!